# how to force IntelliJ to read local maven repository or download from web when it loses track of dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-2020

I'm using IntelliJ ultimate 2020.1.2.

When on any reason one of dependency is removed from `.m2` or missing, it couldn't recognize the changes and reimport it again.

I have already tried with `reimports button` but no effect and I think `invalidating cashes` may will help but this is not an option for me due to re indexing consumes time.

**Is there any other way to set up in IntelliJ or using any `command/button` to force IntelliJ to perform reimporting ?**

Comment: Are you sure that the `offline` mode is not an enabled?

Comment: No, offline mode is unchecked. It happens because I removed one of org subdirectory in .m2 repo.

Comment: did you try to run a maven / gradle build? Because they will download the dependencies automatically. And then you can try a reimport

Comment: Yes I did, even I tried rebuild project.

Comment: can you post a screenshot with your problem? I'm not sure to really understand the problem then

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution just I used `invalidating cashes` and restated IntelliJ.